# AngularJS Correct Use of Replace and Transclude in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive that pulls in my .CSS file (with some additional logic).

It is written in my markup as:

```
<head>
    <link my-style />
    ....
```

And my directive as:

```
app.directive('myStyle', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />',
    transclude: true
  };
});
```

However inspecting the result html, i see:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" my-style="">
/* Put your css in here */
p {
color: red;
}
</link>
```

Specifically, what is the purpose of:

```
my-style=""
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/I6om40ZfRZbETwsbl3MO?p=preview

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the purpose of `my-style`"? - this is what causes the `$compile` service to process your directive

Comment: @NewDev - I saw an empty tag in my mark up so i've asked a question to make sure im following correct an best practices.. Empty markup tags usually raises the question of if its really needed... So i changed my directive an removed the transclude, this had no impact on the result or the result markup.. Hence why i am asking if i have written a directive correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a basis for the is-really-needed question - there are attributes without a value in HTML. As for `transclude` - this is not at all needed as per the directive as you have defined here. Again, I'm not at all understanding neither the issue nor the question